# Could not attach to pid : “8102”

Tags: ios, xcode, error-handling

Does anyone have a permanent fix for the "Could not attach to pid: “8102”" error?
Every time I run a program for the first time, this error pops up. Then I have to run a clean and it works fine. But after I close the simulator and try to run the program again, same error pops up and the process starts over, which is getting really annoying now.

All the solutions I've come across so far just suggest to running a clean or cleaning the build folder, but I'm looking for something that's permanent.

Comment: Have you tried to reset the content and settings in the simulator?

Comment: What do you mean? How do I reset the simulator?

Comment: If you have simulator open, go to hardware tab. There you see "Erase All Content and Settings"